# Why does Visual Studio continue build after Stop debugging?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, debugging, build

I have a Visual Studio solution with roughly 90 projects in it (mixture of Windows Forms in C#/VB.NET,WPF and Silverlight stuff). I have a Windows Forms application (C#) as the startup app. I press F5 to start debugging.

When I exit the debugged application by selecting Stop Debugging in Visual Studio or by selecting Exit in the debugged application, Visual Studio continues the compilation of different assemblies. I have seen no pattern in what assemblies are compiled and it doesn't happen every time.

If I press F5 to start a debugging session, why would Visual Studio continue to build assemblies *after* I have finished debugging?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe those assemblies that are compiled after your application launches do not affect your application and VS wants to launch your application as early as possible?

Comment: So if these assemblies does not have any effect on my application, why would Visual Studio compile them to start with? I have tried enabling "Only build startup projects and dependencies on Run" but that have not changed anything.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked your solution's Configuration Properties ? You can specify there which projects to be built.

Comment: Do you mean the Configuration Manager? My VS solution consists of several different executables which are a part of the same product. Sometimes I want to run one of the application, the next minut I want to run one of the other ones. My question is why Visual Studio builds stuff *after* I have stopped debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Edit-and-continue?  If so, it's rebuilding the edited assemblies.

Comment: Not sure, but I'm sure I'm not editing my code while debugging it.